# Как записать массив в IntPtr

Tags: c#

Как записать массив  в IntPtr

```
 float[,] point = new float[3, 3]{
                                        {  0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f},
                                        { -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f},
                                        {  1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f}
                                       };
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А зачем вам такое понадобилось? Может быть, вам просто нужно правильное объявление P/Invoke?

Comment: @VladD Выложил скрин, там показано.

Comment: Лучше бы Вы предоставили текстовое описание вместо картинки.

Answer (score 1):

Вам по идее нужно что-то такое:

```
float[,] point = new float[3, 3] { ... };
fixed (float* ptr = points)
{
    IntPtr ip = (IntPtr)ptr;
    // тут можно пользоваться
}
```

Учтите, что фиксация адреса при этом будет работать только внутри `fixed`. Это важно: если функция, которой вы передаёте `IntPtr`, запомнит его внутри, и будет использовать его и после окончания `fixed`, ждите беды.

(Да, это сложно, но вы ведь сами выбрали unsafe-программирование.)

---

Если вам нужна постоянно фиксированная память, используйте `Marshal.AllocHGlobal`. В вашем случае это будет выглядеть так:

```
IntPtr points = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(sizeof(float) * 3 * 3);
float* pointptr = (float*)points;
pointptr[0] =  0.0f; // первая строка
pointptr[1] =  1.0f;
pointptr[2] =  0.0f;
pointptr[3] = -1.0f; // вторая строка
pointptr[4] = -1.0f;
pointptr[5] =  0.0f;
pointptr[6] =  1.0f; // третья строка
pointptr[7] = -1.0f;
pointptr[8] =  0.0f;
```

Не забудьте `Marshal.FreeHGlobal(points);` в точке, где вам больше не понадобится эта память.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/589219/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2-gl-glbufferdata?noredirect=1#comment789771_589219

Comment: Посмотрите эту тему пож-та.

Comment: @SVD102: А чем тот вопрос отличается от этого?

Answer (score 0):

Есть несколько вариантов. Первый из них это GCHandle.Alloc
https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.runtime.interopservices.gchandle(v=vs.110).aspx

```
TextWriter tw = System.Console.Out;
        GCHandle gch = GCHandle.Alloc(tw);

        CallBack cewp = new CallBack(CaptureEnumWindowsProc);

        // platform invoke will prevent delegate to be garbage collected
        // before call ends

        LibWrap.EnumWindows(cewp, GCHandle.ToIntPtr(gch));
        gch.Free();
```

Второй вариант это скопировать данный используя нативный менеджер памяти
Получив массив байт через [Buffer.BlockCopy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.buffer.blockcopy(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
static  void УстановитьМассивБайтВIntPtr(byte[] value, IntPtr Элемент)
        {

    // Вызвать нативный метод для выделении памяти
            IntPtr ВыделеннаяПамять = AutoWrap.ВыделитьПямять(value.Length);
            Marshal.Copy(value, 0, ВыделеннаяПамять, value.Length);

            Marshal.WriteIntPtr(Элемент, ВыделеннаяПамять);

            IntPtr текПоз = Элемент + Marshal.SizeOf<IntPtr>();
            Marshal.WriteInt32(текПоз, value.Length);

        }
```

или выделить память через  Marshal.AllocHGlobal и [Метод Marshal.Copy (IntPtr, Single[], Int32, Int32)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/a53bd6cz(v=vs.110).aspx)